ReduceRegion for multiple masks and multiple regions in the Google Earth Engine
Per day, I want to compute the average snow cover for different areas (polygons) and different elevation classes (masks). As a result, I want a table with a date per row and the area_elevation combo per column.
Expected result



date
roi1_elvationA
roi1_elevationB
roi2_elevationA
roi2_elevationB




2024_01_01
xx
xx
xx
xx


2024_01_02
xx
xx
xx
xx


...







My Google Earth Engine Code
can be accessed here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/30901c8b6c14137f0bb9295b96704a1f
I tried the following:
TRY MAPPING APPROACH #1:
IDEA: accumulate attributes over mapped functions
PROBLEM: Error: A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations
to accumulate the attrubutes over mapped functions:the following:
var testMap = ee.ImageCollection(
  snowCover.map(function(snowCoverIm) {
    var date = snowCoverIm.get('system:index');
    var attributes = ee.List([]);

    altitudes.map(function(altitude) {
      var altiName = altitude.get('altitude');
      var masked = snowCoverIm.updateMask(altitude);

      areas.map(function(area) {
        var areaName = area.get('name');
        var meanSnowCover = masked.reduceRegion({
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          geometry: area.geometry(),
        }).get('NDSI_Snow_Cover'); // Get the mean value

        var name_area_alti = ee.String('snowCov_')
          .cat(areaName)
          .cat('_')
          .cat(altiName);

        attributes = attributes.add(ee.Dictionary([[name_area_alti, meanSnowCover]]));
        return null; // Return null to satisfy the map function
      });

      return null; // Return null to satisfy the map function
    });

    attributes = ee.Dictionary(attributes.flatten());

    return ee.Feature(null)
      .set(attributes)
      .set('date', date);
  })
);

TRY MAPPING APPROACH #2
PROBLEM:
each date is listed for each altitude_area combo.
QUESTIONS:
how can I summarize all the area_altitude combos per day?
can the column names for the 'selectors' be automatically produced within this step?
var testMap2 = ee.FeatureCollection(
  snowCover.map(function(snowCoverIm) {
    var date = snowCoverIm.get('system:index');
    return altitudes.map(function(altitude) {
      var altiName = altitude.get('altitude');
      var masked = snowCoverIm.updateMask(altitude);
      return areas.map(function(area) {
        var areaName = area.get('name');
        var meanSnowCover = masked.reduceRegion({
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          geometry: area.geometry(),
        });
        var name_area_alti = ee.String('snowCov_')
          .cat(areaName)
          .cat('_')
          .cat(altiName);
        return ee.Feature(null)
          .set('date', date)
          .set(ee.String(name_area_alti), meanSnowCover.get('NDSI_Snow_Cover')); // Ensure you get the value
      });
    }).flatten(); // Flatten the nested lists
  }).flatten() // Flatten the outer list
);

MANUAL, UGLY APPROACH (works)
The following code gives me the expected result but I want to automatize it instead of manually assigning the area_elevation combos.
var manual = ee.FeatureCollection(
  snowCover.map(function(snowCoverIm) {
    var date = snowCoverIm.get('system:index');
    
    var out = ee.Feature(null)
      .set('date', date)

    // ALTI dem_lt_1000
    var altitude = dem_lt_1000;
    var altiName = altitude.get('altitude');
    var masked = snowCoverIm.updateMask(altitude);
    var sc_roi1 = masked.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: roi1}).get('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
    var sc_roi2 = masked.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: roi2}).get('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
    out = out
      .set(ee.String('snowCov_roi1_').cat(altiName), sc_roi1)
      .set(ee.String('snowCov_roi2_').cat(altiName), sc_roi2)

    
    // ALTI dem_1000_1500
    var altitude = dem_1000_1500;
    var altiName = altitude.get('altitude');
    var masked = snowCoverIm.updateMask(altitude);
    var sc_roi1 = masked.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: roi1}).get('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
    var sc_roi2 = masked.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: roi2}).get('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
    out = out
      .set(ee.String('snowCov_roi1_').cat(altiName), sc_roi1)
      .set(ee.String('snowCov_roi2_').cat(altiName), sc_roi2)
    
    return out
  })
);


Mapped functions can't have side effects, so trying to modify the attributes list in the inner functions isn't possible.  Instead, just return the values up the call stack (instead of returning null) and it should work fine.
